# Using maven pom to export values in xml file

Tags: xml, maven, database-connection

Could someone tell me if it is possible to export a value from a maven pom.xml to an other xml file. I tried this way but it doesn't work.

Pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <database.url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</database.url>
</properties>
```

OtherFile.xml

```
<database id="prod_db" url="${database.url}" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" user="a" password="b" />
```

The xml file cannot understand what is.

Comment: It was there, but it needed some indentation in order for it to be shown :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the folder containing the xml file a resource folder using the Pom file syntax and make sure to set filtering to true.

```
  ...
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
  </resource>
  ...
```